# Okay to have groundcover at base of trees and shrubs?

Tags: ground-cover

I am an inexperienced gardener looking for some advice on whether to pare back the groundcover from around the base of trees and shrubs.

My garden was planted by landscapers around a year ago for my new house. Since then the ground cover ([*Myoporum parvifolium*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myoporum_parvifolium) ) has taken off and is spreading everywhere including covering the base of the vines (ornamental grape vine), shrubs and trees (japanese maples). Should i be cutting a space in the groundcover around the base of other plants?

Regards

Alex

Comment: https://www.abc.net.au/gardening/how-to/native-tidy-up/9437508 "Don't prune hard every year; tip-pruning is usually enough. It's also a good time to re-train groundcovers, to get the ground you want covered, covered! Try pinning into place with something like a tent peg, coat-hanger, rock or purpose-made landscaping pin."

Answer (score 1):

I am also an inexperienced gardener so please take this with a grain - no, a bucket - of salt.

Effects of groundcover:

- Reduced water evaporation. Water your tree less often. This is the main part.
- Fewer weeds.
- Zero chance to plant flowers(probably that is zero problem for You).

Etcetera. All this points to indeed planting a groundcover. AFTER a more experienced user of this website advises so.